# Doctype and sections

Tags: css, html, layout, doctype

I run into this, and I am not sure why it is happening...

Taking the html below as an example, as it is, it will display grey areas for the sections as instructed by the CSS. However, when I include `<!Doctype html>` in the first line it breaks down..  Furthermore, the code below does not work at all with IE9.. why? 
Many thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
.sec_class{
        width:50%;
        height:15%;
        border:1px black solid;
        padding:0px;
        position:relative;
        background-color:grey;
}
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<section class = 'sec_class'></section>
<section class = 'sec_class'></section>
<section class = 'sec_class'></section>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `section`s have basically no height, because `height` given in the percentage (`height: 15%;`) will always be [relative to the parent's height](http://webdesign.about.com/od/csstutorials/f/set-css-height-100-percent.htm). `body` has zero height in your case, and the 15% of that is still zero.

This should help:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }​
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bazmegakapa/TeYk7/)

*Be sure to ALWAYS include the doctype.*

Comment: Yes, this helps a lot. I didn't think that omitting this would cause problems, many thanks!

Comment: You said this quite clearly, but just to reiterate, the issue is *not* because the `positon` was set to relative, but because the height was set to a percentage.  Setting the height to 15px would also have expanded the sections (as is true with any block element).  Also, setting either the html element or the body element alone does not fix the issue (at least not in chrome). Both must be set (which was a surprise to me). You can (if you are so inclined) substitute `html` with the newer `:root`, but `body` will still need a height.

Answer (score 1):

In order to make IE styles HTML5 tags (`section`, `nav`...) you must use a polyfill, because it can't by default. You can use: http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

It's just a JS file that you must include on your HTML (using IE conditional comments):

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Also you should not use single quotes:

```
<section class="sec_class"></section>
```

Also, of course, if you are setting a porcentual height on your `section` elements, his parent must have also a defined height. On your case, a 15% height of nothing (`body` has no height) is… nothing.

Comment: Single quotes are fine in HTML5. Also he says his problem does appear in IE9.

Comment: He says it does not work at all in IE9 (because of height issue). On other browsers (other IE maybe) it doesn't work when adding doctype (HTML5 shiv stuff).

Comment: Juan, many thanks for your answer. Bažmegakapa's answered solved my issue, but I will for sure check out polyfill.